# JS: add object ID to edit URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code where in second section there is `jQuery.each()` loop where I get object  `id`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
      table: "#user_groups_table",
      template: '#user_groups_form',
      display: "details",
      idSrc: "id",
      ajax: {
          edit: {
              type: 'PATCH',
              url:  '/strongbolt/user_groups/' // Here I need to add object id
          }
      },
      fields: [ {
              name: "name"
          }, {
              name: "description"
          }
      ]
    } );

// Here we modify params before they are sent to server
    editor.on( 'preSubmit', function ( e, data, action ) {
      if ( action === 'create' ) {
        // create action code...
      } else if ( action === 'edit' ) {
        $.each( data.data, function (id, value) {
        data.strongbolt_user_group = {
          "name": data.data[id].name,
          "description": data.data[id].description,
        };
        });
        delete data.data;
      }
 } );
```

How do I pass that object `id`, so I can have my `edit` action URL something like this: `url:  '/strongbolt/user_groups/' + id` ? Thank you!

**Update**

`data.data` gives me params like this, where [90] is `id`:

```
action  edit
data[90][name]  My_test_group_name
data[90][description]   My_test_description
```

**Update 2**

Is there any option from me to pass `rowId` variable from the code below to my `edit` action URL above, please?

```
else if ( action === 'edit' ) {
  $.each( data.data, function (id, value) {
    var rowId = id;
    console.log(rowId);
  data.strongbolt_user_group = {
    "name": data.data[rowId].name,
    "description": data.data[rowId].description,
    };
   });
  delete data.data;
 }
```

**The solution**

I'm sorry to say, but the solution is simple - I had to pass url as suggested here in [Editor Datatables docs](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#URL-parameters).

Comment: From where do you get the id?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen It's JSON object with id, e.g., { id: 90 }

Comment: Have you included that part in your code? I can't seem to spot it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please, see my update above - this is what I see in my params on submit and it comes from that `data.data`

Comment: If the id comes from data.data and you loop through that, how do you know what id you want? or does data.data only contains 1 elements

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen in my `edit` action's `.each()` loop I do it for single object, where I have single `id`.